# How can I plot more than one figure in the same JPEG file in R?

Tags: r, plot

Here is the code for the plot I'm doing iteratively and storing it in different files.

```
lab=unique(train_train$PdDistrict)
lab=as.character(lab)
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(9,4,1,0))
for(i in 1:length(lab))
{
   jpeg(file=mypath,quality=100,width=1024,height=768)
  mypath=file.path("C:","Users","sujit_000","Desktop",paste("PDdistrict",i,".jpeg",sep=""))
   a=plot(table(train_train[train_train$PdDistrict==lab[i],1]),las=2,main=lab[i])
   dev.off()
}
```

The JPEG files I'm getting with this is 1 image per file like shown, but I want it to save two images per file.

[image]

Comment: Use the `layout`-function. I don't think jpeg-format has a multi-page option. For that you would need PDF or PS.

Comment: if a `pdf` would be fine, you can put `pdf("myplot.pdf")`  before your script, and `dev.off()` at the bottom. but @42 is right, it won't work with `jpeg()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want two pages per file, each with a plot (as the comments suggest and correctly say won't work with jpeg) , or two plots in a single page/file?

Given the `mfrow` argument you used in `par`, I'll assume you want to latter. A couple of points to accomplish that:

- Call `par` after `jpeg`, otherwise each call to `jpeg` is resetting the device options.
- I imagine you actually want to define `mypath` *before* creating the device, otherwise it will be missing for the first file and the rest will be shifted by one.
- You'll want to have two calls to plot, one for each of the plots you want together. Presumably you would also want to change the for-loop sequence to skip every other (assuming you want two consecutive ones plotted together).

Try something like this:

```
lab=unique(train_train$PdDistrict)
lab=as.character(lab)
## changed loop to every other
for(i in seq(1, length(lab), by=2))
{
  ## moved mypath before jpeg(), should mypath inclue both i and i+1 in name?
  mypath=file.path("C:","Users","sujit_000","Desktop",paste("PDdistrict",i,".jpeg",sep=""))
  jpeg(file=mypath,quality=100,width=1024,height=768)
  ## moved par() from outside of loop
  par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(9,4,1,0))
  ## removed unnecessary assignment of plot()
  plot(table(train_train[train_train$PdDistrict==lab[i],1]),las=2,main=lab[i])
  ## added second plot for i+1
  plot(table(train_train[train_train$PdDistrict==lab[i+1],1]),las=2,main=lab[i+1])
  dev.off()
}
```

This will break on the last `i+1` call if you have an odd number of plots, but that's a straightforward fix if necessary.